# Why does Flutter ship the Skia engine despite using AOT compilation to native code?

Tags: flutter, dart, skia

I'm currently exploring Flutter's architecture and compilation process, and I'm a bit puzzled by the presence of the Skia engine even when Flutter uses AOT (Ahead-of-Time) compilation to generate native machine code.

As far as I understand, AOT compilation should convert the Dart code into native code, However, I noticed that Flutter still ships the Skia engine

I'd like to understand the reasoning behind this design decision. Why does Flutter need the Skia engine when it already compiles the Dart code to native machine code? What benefits does Skia provide in conjunction with AOT compilation? Are there specific performance or cross-platform considerations that make the inclusion of Skia?

Comment: The compiled Dart code takes the process right down to the skia level.  But skia isn't present in an accessible view on chrome, so yes, the flutter payload brings along its own skia.